# With subscribers and status updates, who's responsibility is it to notify subscribers?

Tags: ruby, oop

Let's say I have a `Subscriber` class and a `StatusUpdate` class. I want all subscribers to receive a notification whenever there's a new `StatusUpdate`.

Here's the way it looks now:

```
class Subscriber
    attr_accessor :number
end
```

And the `StatusUpdate` class:

```
class StatusUpdate
    attr_accessor :status

    def initializer(body)
        @body = body
        notify_subscribers
    end

    private

    def notify_subscribers
        Subscriber.all.each do |subscriber|
            # some code to send an SMS to the subscriber
        end
    end
end
```

But looking at this code it occurred to me that the responsibility of notifying subscribers should perhaps lie with the `Subscriber` class, and I should perhaps move the `notify_subscribers` method there and call it from `StatusUpdate`'s `initialize` (something like `Subscriber.notify_all(message)`), but that also looked kind of messy to me.

What would be the proper OO way to do this? Is notifying subscribers the responsibility of the `Subscriber` class? `StatusUpdate` class? Or perhaps some third class?

P.S. The code is in Ruby, but I guess it's more of a general Object Oriented design question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things, and this is of course something you can do one way or another:

- you might want to move the notification (sending text message) to a background job, as this is potentially blocking
- neither Subscriber nor StatusUpdate should do the notification, they just hold the information relavant to that status update
- I'd create a Service which takes care of the notification

Something like

```
class SendNotifications
  def initialize(status_update)
    @status_update = status_update
  end

  def call
    Subscriber.find_each do |subscriber|
      Notifier.perform_async(subscriber.mobile, status_update.body)
    end
  end

  private
  attr_reader :status_update
end
```